# Effective dose (ED) in the drc package

Tags: r

I'm using the drc package in R, and after calculating the model I try to use the function ED to get the effective dose at several levels (IC50, IC75, IC90...), however from time to time I get the following error message and I don't seem to find any information on how to solve it.

Error in EDlist(parmChosen, respLev[j], reference = reference, type = type,  : 
  could not find function "EDhelper"

The package is properly installed and loaded, and after checking the documentation it seems EDhelper is indeed no function but rather something else required by the function which R doesn't seem to find anymore.

Sorry for the trouble but any help would be very much appreaciated!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to actually post the error message.

Comment: True, sorry about that, it is included now.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what the issue is, because I can't see your data. It may be that EDhelper has been discontinued. I am also working with Dose-Response curves in DRC, the following works for me:

```
mod1 <- drm(ratio ~ dose, weights = total, data = data_source1, type ="binomial", fct=LL.2())


ED(mod1, c(10, 20, 50, 90, 99), interval = "delta", reference = "control")
```

or perhaps

```
ED(mod1,50,interval="fls")
```